# How to manage incorrect input

Tags: java

I am trying to take input in the form of two different integers separated by a space ex: `14 2`.

I am having trouble finding a way to prompt the user to try again if the input is either a double instead of an int, a character, or basically anything that isn't two integers separated by a space.

I dont really want to use `exceptions and try/catch` statements because I don't understand them.

I would rather either take in a string[] arr and use split(" ") or just do `console.nextInt();`. Any feedback would be great. I know it is not pretty.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean ok = true;
boolean ok2 = true;
while (ok = true){
for(int i = 0; i<=2; i++){

if(!console.hasNextInt()){
    kb.next();
    System.out.println("Bad input, try again");
    ok2 false;
}
else if(i = 0 && ok2 = true){
    int a = console.hasNextInt();
}
else if(i = 1 && ok2 = true){
    int b = console.hasNextInt();
    ok = false; //means there are two #s and the program can continue with a and b   

}

else{
}
 }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254431/check-and-see-if-an-element-in-a-two-dimensional-array-is-of-a-certain-data-type/24254636#24254636

Comment: how about using regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont really want to use exceptions and try/catch statements because I don't understand them." If you want to be into programming, you MUST learn about exceptions.

Comment: I get the idea I just done know which would be thrown and then how i would use the error. Is that a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using Scanner#hasNextInt() to validate the input:

```
    final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    final List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer : ");

        if (console.hasNextInt())
        {
            input.add(console.nextInt());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Bad input, try again ...");
            console.next();
        }
        if (input.size() >= 2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("First integer entered was : " + input.get(0));
    System.out.println("Second integer entered was : " + input.get(1));
```

Comment: If the input isnt an int wont it break?

Comment: I don't think so.  console.hasNextInt() is called to check the input before console.nextInt().  You just keep getting the error message.  Of course you're in an infinite loop until you correctly enter two integers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following code accepts input till it gets positive number only. Negative & zero numbers are handled by while loop condition. and characters are handled using `!sc.hasNextInt()` in another while loop condition.

```
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number : ");
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid number.");
                sc.next(); 
            }
            number = sc.nextInt();
        } while (number <= 0);
        System.out.println("Recieved a Positive number = " + number+". Thanks!");
```

Output-

```
Please enter a positive number : 
-1
Please enter a positive number : 
0
Please enter a positive number : 
n
That is not a valid number.
6
Recieved a Positive number = 6. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to write as simple and as easy code as possible,

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter two numbers  ");

String str = console.readLine();

String values[] = str.split(" ");

int n1, n2;

try{
    n1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
    //Convert first String value to int, if it will be anything else than int
    // then it will throw the NumberFormatException
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("First number is not integer");
}

try{
    n2 = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
    //Convert second String value to int, if it will be anything else than int
    // then it will throw the NumberFormatException
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("Second number is not integer");
}
```

**Note**

This code is based on assumption that there will be *only* Two elements entered by the user. NOT more than two. In that case, code will be needed to change.

Comment: This doesn't catch indexoutofbounds exceptions

Comment: Great this is what I was working with earlier I just didnt know how to  implement the catch. thank you

Comment: @Davio Definitey Yes, it doesn't I forgot to write my assumption in code. Thanks for pointing out.